# Authentification and Authorization with WinForms (IsInRole Method)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to repeat an exercise from the book (*"C# 7.0: All-in-One-for-Dummies"*) which shows how authentification and authorization works in WinForms. And everything compiles and there are no issues during runtime but it doesn't works as intended.

Let me explain in details:

I have three buttons (Sales, Accountancy and HR) and I have the code which allows only the member of the appropriate group to be able to see this button (by the way, buttons' `.Visible = false`). I made an additional User (with the user rights and not administrator) and Groups for experimentation and added this User to each Group consequently. What I mean. I added the user to the group and then check the result. After this I deleted user from the group and add him to the next one. And so on.

The result is that sometimes I can see all buttons and some times I can't see only one button (but not the intended one) and it seems like my code doesn't affect a thing or affect it in a weird manner. I have no idea what is going on. My Windows is 7 Home Advanced and I am working with groups and users via CMD with `net localgroup` and `net user`. I read Microsoft description for `IsInRole` method and it seems like I did everything correct because if you indicate string with the name of the group it means the exact group in your Windows. Here is the code itself:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace AuthentificationAndAuthorization
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowsIdentity userIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal userRights = new WindowsPrincipal(userIdentity);

             if (userRights.IsInRole("Accountancy")) AccountingButton.Visible = true;
             else if (userRights.IsInRole("Sales")) SalesButton.Visible = true;
             else if (userRights.IsInRole("HR")) ManagerButton.Visible = true;
             else if (userRights.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)) AccountingButton.Visible = true; SalesButton.Visible = true; ManagerButton.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a book that's already 4 versions out-of-date? C# 7.0 was released in 2017, we're now up to C# 11.0.

Comment: _"My Windows is 7 Home Advanced"_ - there is no SKU of Windows 7 called "Home Advanced" - do you mean _Home Premium_ instead?

Comment: I think the problem is your last `else if` branch has `SalesButton.Visible = true; ManagerButton.Visible = true;` - but those statements are not part of the `if` statement because you aren't using curly-braces (this is why my `.editorconfig` file disallows using braceless multiline `if` statements: it's dangerous).

Comment: Yes! Sorry for mistranslation. Of course it's a Home Premium. I will check out you suggestion about braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried some debugging and did nothing else it started to work as I expect all of a sudden. This is cryptic...Also I found that builin Administrator can see all buttons no matter what you code tells. Ok. Nevermind.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem: **don't use `if` without braces**. [It's what caused Apple's 2014 iOS security nightmare](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).

Change this:

```cs
if (userRights.IsInRole("Accountancy")) AccountingButton.Visible = true;
else if (userRights.IsInRole("Sales")) SalesButton.Visible = true;
else if (userRights.IsInRole("HR")) ManagerButton.Visible = true;
else if (userRights.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)) AccountingButton.Visible = true; SalesButton.Visible = true; ManagerButton.Visible = true;
```

to this:

```cs
if (userRights.IsInRole("Accountancy"))
{
    this.AccountingButton.Visible = true;
}
else if (userRights.IsInRole("Sales"))
{
    this.SalesButton.Visible = true;
}
else if (userRights.IsInRole("HR"))
{
    this.ManagerButton.Visible = true;
}
else if (userRights.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
{
    this.AccountingButton.Visible = true;
    this.SalesButton.Visible = true;
    this.ManagerButton.Visible = true;
}
```

....or better yet, do this:

```cs
Boolean isAdmin = userRights.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

this.AccountingButton.Visible = userRights.IsInRole("Accountancy") || isAdmin;
this.SalesButton     .Visible = userRights.IsInRole("Sales")       || isAdmin;
this.ManagerButton   .Visible = userRights.IsInRole("HR")          || isAdmin;
```

Also, avoid using *magic strings*: if you move those role-names to be `const String` values in a `static class` then your code will be easier to maintain in future.

Comment: Thank you for a very good and valid advices! Actually what you suggest doesn't help me either. I tried many possible combinations. I even commented the whole section of code regards to rights and my user still can see Sales button. I have no idea of what is going on. Really. Probably their is some sort of a problem with Windows itself (I have Windows in language different from English). But anyway the names of the groups which I added are in plain English...